# Conditional values in Pandas with progression

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, loops, iterator

I have a data frame:

```
           store_id    period   sales    t
512944     38126926    241    3.9500    1.0
832513     38126935    240    0.9500    1.0
417892     38126935    242    4.6500    2.0
354468     38126938    241    5.1000    1.0
604276     38126938    242    3.2765    1.0
```

I need to iterate from top to bottom and recursively assign values from a list. Each time value in COLUMN 'T' changes from 1 > 2 i need to take next value from the list.

For example:

```
if value in COLUMN 'T' is 1:
    then use first item from a list
if value in COLUMN 'T' is more then 1:
    then use NEXT item from the list
```

So each time value in COLUMN 'T' changes from 1 to another number take next item from the list and keep assigning it (new column).

I m stuck with algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a suggestion:

**Method 1:**

First create a dictionary from your list of values. Assuming your list of values is called `my_list`:

```
my_list = ['just', 'some', 'values']
mapping = {key: val for key, val in enumerate(my_list)}
```

Now you can assign the values to column `list_val` as follows:

```
df['list_val'] = df.t.eq(2).cumsum().map(mapping)
```

**Method 2:**

Alternatively, you can also do the following, which does not require creating `mapping`:

```
df['list_val'] = df.t.eq(2).cumsum().apply(lambda x: my_list[x])
```

Now `df` looks as follows:

```
        store_id  period   sales    t list_val
512944  38126926     241  3.9500  1.0     just
832513  38126935     240  0.9500  1.0     just
417892  38126935     242  4.6500  2.0     some
354468  38126938     241  5.1000  1.0     some
604276  38126938     242  3.2765  1.0     some
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly: If we call your dataframe `df` and the list `value_list`
Then we can take do something like this

```
# create column with all values as first element of list 
df['new_col'] = value_list[0]

# get boolean vector for filtering the dataframe
df_filter = df['t'] != 1 

# reduce the list so we only have the elements that we would use
value_list = value_list[1:sum(df_filter)]

# reassign the values of `new_col` with value_list
df.loc[df_filter, 'new_col'] = value_list
```

Now the column `new_col` should have what you need.

If I misunderstood and your problem needs only a list with two elements then you should change the  reassign line to

```
df.loc[df_filter, 'new_col'] = value_list[1]
```

without filtering the value_list down

Answer (score 0):

first let's read the data:

```py
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

s = """           store_id    period   sales    t
512944     38126926    241    3.9500    1.0
832513     38126935    240    0.9500    1.0
417892     38126935    242    4.6500    2.0
354468     38126938    241    5.1000    1.0
604276     38126938    242    3.2765    1.0"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep='\s+')
```

I think this is what you need:

```py
i = 0
mylist = [4, 5]
for ix, row in df.iterrows():
    if row.t == 1:
        df.loc[ix, 'newcol'] = mylist[0]
    else:
        i += 1
        df.loc[ix, 'newcol'] = mylist[i]
print(df)
```

```
        store_id  period   sales    t  newcol
512944  38126926     241  3.9500  1.0     4.0
832513  38126935     240  0.9500  1.0     4.0
417892  38126935     242  4.6500  2.0     5.0
354468  38126938     241  5.1000  1.0     4.0
604276  38126938     242  3.2765  1.0     4.0
```

Comment: Sry not really what i need. My bad explanation possibly. I need to ASSIGN A NEW item  from LIST/ DICT on EVERY change '1 > 2' .